# vb.net - how to check if current time is between two time

Tags: vb.net, time

How do I check if my current time is between 06:00:00 AM and 11:00:00 AM?

Is it something like this?

```
If Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") >= "06:00:00 AM" and Now.ToString <= "11:00:00 AM" Then
     'Do something
End If
```

I'm sorry. I'm still learning.

Comment: You cant do math comparisons on strings.  The `DateTime` type has properties so that you can compare Hour, Mon, Sec etc

Comment: Can I get a sample for that?

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now` rather than `Now`, which is a VB6 holdover. It's `TimeOfDay` property will give you a `TimeSpan` that represents the current time. You can compare that to another `TimeSpan` that you create to represent a specific time. If you want a sample, look it up. I'm sure that the Help menu in your copy of VS works the same way mine does.and that you have the same access to search engines on the web.

Comment: Convert your time to 24 hour format and it'd be easier to compare them

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there ought to be an easier way to do this, but if there is, I can't think of it.  Here's the easiest/safest way I came up with to do it:

```
Dim curr As Date = Date.Now
Dim startTime As New Date(curr.Year, curr.Month, curr.Day, 6, 0, 0)
Dim endTime As New Date(curr.Year, curr.Month, curr.Day, 11, 0, 0)
If (curr >= startTime) And (curr <= endTime) Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.  I would do it with 24 hour clock to avoid ambiguity:

```
Dim timeNow As String = Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
If timeNow >= "06:00:00" And timeNow <= "11:00:00" Then
     'Do something`
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Good. Here is an updated version. Convert 24hour clock time to an integer then do logic on Integers

```
Dim timeValue As Integer = Now.ToString("HHmm")
If timeValue >= 600 and timeValue <= 1100 Then
    ' do it now
End If
```